# Android IMAGE_CAPTURE always returns Activity.RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, camera

I want to take a photo in my app. On the emulator everything works fine.
But on the tablet, the Intent immediately returns Activity.RESULT_CANCELED in onActivityResult. The picture is saved on the SD Card.

Here is the code for taking picture:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
String tmpFile = CommonFunctions.generateRandomFileName() + ".jpg";
String fileName = CommonFunctions.getNoticeSavePath() + tmpFile;
System.out.println("Filename " + fileName);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)));
notice.setBild(tmpFile);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PICTURE);
```

Code for onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    switch (requestCode) {

        case RESULT_PICTURE:
            System.out.println("ResultCode" + resultCode);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            }
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                notice.setBild("");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bild wurde nicht hinzugefügt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Permissions are set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

The result is always RESULT_CANCELED, but the photo is stored correctly on the sd card.
What could the problem be?

Comment: is you `Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)));` correct path ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The photo is saved there

Comment: Have you mark the launch mode of your activity as `singleInstance`?

Comment: Try installing a third-party camera app and see what the behavior is when you choose it instead of the built-in one to handle this request. My guess is that it is simply a bug in the built-in camera app implementation.

Comment: Hi, I have nothing selected for Launch Mode. What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1, SELECT_FILE = 2; //global
```

onresult method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bm = null;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {

                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),btmapOptions);
                bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 300, 200, true);

                String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+ "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";

                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().putString("endum_image_", f.toString()).commit();

                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) 
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            //getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);

            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, Signup2Activity.this);
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().putString("endum_image_", tempPath).commit();

            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath,btmapOptions);
            bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 300, 200, true);

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);

        }
    }



        imSex.setImageBitmap(bm);
        flag= true;

    }
```